# Are there any minimum degree $3$ graphs (order $\ge$ $8$) that have $4$ cycles but no $8$ cycles?

Tags: graph-theory

I was reading about the Erdős–Gyárfás conjecture and playing around with some graphs that have vertices of minimum degree $3$. While there are some graphs (Petersen, for example) that don't have $4$ cycles, it seemed like if a graph has a $4$ cycle, it also definitely has an $8$ cycle; or if a graph has an $8$ cycle, then it definitely has a $16$ cycle. I was wondering if anyone had any counterexamples.

Comment: Do they have to be simple graphs? (I.e. no loops, no multiple edges) Also, what counts as a cycle? Seems like running around a 4-cycle twice gives an 8-cycles.

Answer (score 2):

[House of Graphs](https://hog.grinvin.org/) finds two graphs that meet these conditions:

```
Your current result list contains all graphs that satisfy the following criteria:
    Number of Vertices >= 8.0
AND Minimum Degree = 3.0
AND Circumference < 8.0
AND Girth = 4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Trivially the [triangular prism graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_graph#/media/File:Triangular_prismatic_graph.png) has a number of $4$-cycles, but since it only has $6$ vertices, of course it does not have an $8$-cycle.

Perhaps your conjecture might be rescued by claiming that if a graph has *two* separate $4$-cycles (for example), it must have an $8$-cycle. However there are still plenty of easy examples where that is not true. In fact a pair of triangular prism graphs joined by a bridging edge would still not have an $8$-cycle, despite having multiple disjoint $4$-cycles. Contracting that bridging edge would still not create an $8$-cycle even though there would now be a vertex which is part of two otherwise distinct $4$-cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do the following, for any positive integer $n$:

1. First, take $n$ vertex-disjoint copies of $K_4$, and for each $i=1,\ldots, n$, let $v_i$ be a vertex in the $i$-th copy of $K_4$.
2. Add for each $i=1,2,\ldots, n-1$ the edge $v_iv_{i+1}$, so that $v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n$ form a path.

It is straightforward to check that the resulting graph from 1. and 2, above has the desired properties.